# jQuery DataTables server-side processing with Java

Tags: jquery, jakarta-ee, datatables

I am looking for how to implement jQuery DataTables with server-side processing in Java. I have tried the following way by using the below parameters. Below is my jQuery `ready` function code.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    //url = http://localhost:8080/jQuery-DataTable-Java-Integration/serverExample
    $('#myTableId').DataTable({
        "serverSide" : true,
        "processing" : true,
        /*"bProcessing" : true,
        "bServerSide" : true,*/
        "ajax" : {
            "url" : "serverExample",
            "type" : "POST"
        },
        "columns" : [ {
            "data" : "Phone Number"
        }, {
            "data" : "name"
        }, {
            "data" : "Email"
        } ]
    });
});
```

In my servlet doPost() method I the request parameter **sEcho** is null.

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        logger.info("In do post method of server servlet..");
        logger.info("sEcho request parameter = " + request.getParameter("sEcho"));//returning null
//other code here
}
```

My jQuery DataTables version is 1.10.7. Which parameters should be used, `serverSide` or `bServerside`, I tried both ways, but still the same. Any latest updated working example references would be helpful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When using DataTables 1.10 version in server-side processing mode, client side sends `draw` parameter along with other parameters. Full list is shown on [DataTables website](https://datatables.net/manual/server-side#Sent-parameters).

Previous version of DataTables 1.9 used `sEcho` parameter in server-side processing mode, see [documentation](http://legacy.datatables.net/usage/server-side) for more information.

If you have server-side script written for DataTables 1.9, it is possible to force DataTables 1.10 to send parameters compatible with previous version. Below is an excerpt from the manual:

> Older versions of DataTables (1.9-) used a different set of parameters
>   to send and receive from the server. As such scripts which are written
>   for DataTables 1.10+ will not be able to function with DataTables
>   1.9-. However, DataTables 1.10 does have a compatibility mode for scripts written for 1.9-. This compatibility mode is triggered by use
>   of the old `sAjaxSource` parameter (rather than the new `ajax`
>   parameter) or by setting`$.fn.dataTable.ext.legacy.ajax = true;` .

You should be using `serverSide` and `processing` which are preferred option names for version 1.10 although it accepts option names (`bServerSide` and `bProcessing`) for previous version as well.